# Getting frequent Kill:9 Error in Xcode and Terminal

Tags: ios, swift, xcode14, macos-ventura, sigkill

I have recently upgraded the Mac OS to Ventura 13.2.1 and Xcode to 14.2, now once I try to compile any application with Xcode, I am getting Kill:9 related issue for random task/framework in the project. I also get Kill:9 issue sometime on terminal as well.

Listing the errors here:

1. failed to read asset tags: The command `` terminated with uncaught signal 9. The command had no output.
2. Driver threw jobFailedWithNonzeroExitCode(9, "") without emitting errors.
3. Unable to execute command: Killed 9 Clang frontend command failed due to signal.

Please help me to resolve this issue/crash.

1. Open project in Xcode.
2. Build the app with Simulator (I tried with iPhone 14 Pro)
3. Error occurs in the build

Ideally project should have compiled without any error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that the problem is with the installation of Xcode because when an unprivileged task is attempted, the OS will kill it off (with signal 9).

What I recommend is for you to re-install Xcode.

When you first run the new Xcode, it should prompt you for an administrator password in order to install system related components.  Make sure you do this step.  Hopefully that should then allow you to compile and run your iOS apps.

Comment: Firstly the issue was also observed on terminal so it was not Xcode related issue, still
I tried to reinstall the Xcode twice or thrice, but with no success. 
Finally I formatted the system and reinstalled everything. Seems like the issue was with Git installed by brew and git installed by Xcode command-line-tools

Comment: Glad you fixed it!